# Aligning two minipages within a bigger minipage

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, minipage

I have two minipages within a bigger minipage. One of them is a graph, which is a figure, the other one a tabula. The issue is, that I want the x-axis of the graph to align with the lower line of the tabula. On top of that, the captions of the two minipages should also be on the same height.
This is, how it currently looks:
[image: Current look]

And it should look like this:

[image: desired look]

Here's the related code snippet:

```
\begin{minipage}[0.25\textheight]{\textwidth}
\begin{minipage}{0.6\linewidth} 
    \centering
      \pgfplotsset{%
        width=0.55\linewidth,
        compat=newest}
      \include{Figures/IOFunction} 
\captionof{figure}{Graph}
\end{minipage} 
\begin{minipage}[t][0.25\textheight][t]{0.35\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{lrr}
        \toprule
        Parameter          & Value & Unit \\
    \midrule
        TEXT INSIDE TABULA
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{Tabula}
\end{minipage}
\end{minipage}
\vspace{10pt}
```

Comment: you need to upload a compilable code

Answer (score 1):

From what you've shown, you would need to add some space between the bottom of the `tabular` and the `\captionof` statement. That's the simplest approach.

I do notice that you've attempted to set heights using the optional argument to `minipage`. The problem here is twofold: (1) your first two lines should probably read:

```
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{minipage}[0.25\textheight]{0.6\linewidth}
```

Note that I moved the optional argument to the inner `minipage`. (2) LaTeX has no idea where to put the extra space it needs (I'm guessing you're getting lots of `underfull  \vbox` messages). I would be inclined to just dispense with the optional arguments on the `minipage`s entirely and just manually set the amount of space you need for the table and graph to line up.

One more thing. I think you meant to say `\input` rather than `\include` when you brought in your figure. `\include` is meant for being able to include (or not include) portions of a document (usually at the chapter or group of chapters level). If it works at all, it's more luck than design.